# Cumulative count of unique values in R

Tags: r, unique, cumulative-sum

A simplified version of my data set would look like:

```
depth value
   1     a
   1     b
   2     a
   2     b
   2     b
   3     c
```

I would like to make a new data set where, for each value of "depth", I would have the cumulative number of unique values, starting from the top. e.g.

```
depth cumsum
 1      2
 2      2
 3      3
```

Any ideas as to how to do this? I am relatively new to R.

Answer (score 14):

I find this a perfect case of using `factor` and setting `levels` carefully. I'll use `data.table` here with this idea. Make sure your `value` column is `character` (not an absolute requirement).

- step 1: Get your `data.frame` converted to `data.table` by taking just `unique` rows.

  ```
  require(data.table)
  dt <- as.data.table(unique(df))
  setkey(dt, "depth") # just to be sure before factoring "value"
  ```
- step 2: Convert `value` to a `factor` and coerce to `numeric`. Make sure to *set the levels yourself* (it is important).

  ```
  dt[, id := as.numeric(factor(value, levels = unique(value)))]
  ```
- step 3: Set key column to `depth` for subsetting and *just pick the last value*

  ```
   setkey(dt, "depth", "id")
   dt.out <- dt[J(unique(depth)), mult="last"][, value := NULL]

  #    depth id
  # 1:     1  2
  # 2:     2  2
  # 3:     3  3
  ```
- step 4: Since all values in the rows with increasing depth should have **at least** the value of the previous row, you should use `cummax` to get the final output.

  ```
  dt.out[, id := cummax(id)]
  ```

**Edit:** The above code was for illustrative purposes. In reality you don't need a 3rd column at all. This is how I'd write the final code.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(unique(df))
setkey(dt, "depth")
dt[, value := as.numeric(factor(value, levels = unique(value)))]
setkey(dt, "depth", "value")
dt.out <- dt[J(unique(depth)), mult="last"]
dt.out[, value := cummax(value)]
```

Here's a more tricky example and the output from the code:

```
df <- structure(list(depth = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6), 
                value = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L), 
                .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g"), class = "factor")), 
                .Names = c("depth", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
                class = "data.frame")
#    depth value
# 1:     1     2
# 2:     2     4
# 3:     3     4
# 4:     4     5
# 5:     5     6
# 6:     6     6
```

Comment: Here's a `dplyr` version: `df %>% arrange(depth) %>% mutate(value = cummax(as.numeric(factor(value, levels = unique(value))))) %>% arrange(depth, desc(value)) %>% distinct(depth)`.

Comment: This method can be generally applied for when both `depth` and `value` are string values. Thanks!

Comment: @Arun This is a great solution! Thanks!

Comment: What if we have a third variable called group and we want to achieve the same results for each group?

Answer (score 12):

A dplyr attempt.

```
df %>%
  #group_by(group)%>% # if you have a third variable and you want to achieve the same results for each group
  mutate(cum_unique_entries = cumsum(!duplicated(value))) %>%
  group_by(depth) %>% # add group variable for more layers
  summarise(cum_unique_entries = last(cum_unique_entries))
```

Comment: This worked nicely for my problem, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 8):

Here is another attempt:

```
numvals <- cummax(as.numeric(factor(mydf$value)))
aggregate(numvals, list(depth=mydf$depth), max)
```

Which gives:

```
  depth x
1     1 2
2     2 2
3     3 3
```

It seems to work with @Arun's example, too:

```
  depth x
1     1 2
2     2 4
3     3 4
4     4 5
5     5 6
6     6 6
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it appears that both `depth` and `value` must be simultaneously sorted. For instance, this method won't count the unique occurrence of `c` no matter how you `setkey()` this `data.table`: `mydf = data.table(data.frame(depth=c(1,1,2,2,6,7), value=c("a", "b", "g", "h", "b", "c")))`.

Answer (score 7):

A good first step would be to create a column of `TRUE` or `FALSE`, where it is `TRUE` for the first of each value and `FALSE` for later appearances of that value. This can be done easily using `duplicated`:

```
mydata$first.appearance = !duplicated(mydata$value)
```

Reshaping the data is best done using `aggregate`. In this case, it says to sum over the `first.appearance` column within each subset of `depth`:

```
newdata = aggregate(first.appearance ~ depth, data=mydata, FUN=sum)
```

The result will look like:

```
  depth first.appearance
1     1  2
2     2  0
3     3  1
```

This is still not a cumulative sum, though. For that you can use the `cumsum` function (and then get rid of your old column):

```
newdata$cumsum = cumsum(newdata$first.appearance)
newdata$first.appearance = NULL
```

So to recap:

```
mydata$first.appearance = !duplicated(mydata$value)
newdata = aggregate(first.appearance ~ depth, data=mydata, FUN=sum)
newdata$cumsum = cumsum(newdata$first.appearance)
newdata$first.appearance = NULL
```

Output:

```
  depth cumsum
1     1      2
2     2      2
3     3      3
```

Comment: nice! you can combine this w/ data.table `DT[, .(depth, unique.count = cumsum(!duplicated(value)))][, .(cumsum = max(unique.count)), by = .(depth)]`

Answer (score 5):

This can be written in a relatively clean fashion with a single SQL statement using the [sqldf](http://sqldf.googlecode.com) package.  Assume `DF` is the original data frame:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select b.depth, count(distinct a.value) as cumsum
    from DF a join DF b 
    on a.depth <= b.depth
    group by b.depth"
)
```

Comment: This is very useful assuming `depth` is numeric. If `depth` is a string or string representation of a date, as it was in my case, it can be a very expensive operation.

Comment: In many cases the speed is unimportant and clarity is the more important issue.  If performance is important then you really have to test it rather than make assumptions and if found too slow add an index and test it again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `lapply()`. With `unique(df$depth)` make vector of unique `depth` values and then for each such value subset only those `value` values where `depth` is equal or less than particular `depth` value. Then calculate length of unique `value` values. This length value is stored in `cumsum`, then `depth=x` will give value of particular depth level.  With `do.call(rbind,...)` make it as one data frame.

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$depth), 
               function(x)
             data.frame(depth=x,cumsum=length(unique(df$value[df$depth<=x])))))
  depth cumsum
1     1      2
2     2      2
3     3      3
```